# Kendo UI Scheduler Datasource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to implement `Kendo UI scheduler`. But I can't seem to get the `datasource` to work.

My JS is:

```
var diary = {
    open: function() {
        dialog('diary', function() {
            $('#diaryDialog').css('width', '1450px');
            $('#calendar').kendoScheduler({
                date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
                startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
                height: 700,
                views: [
                    "day",
                    {type: "workWeek", selected: true},
                    "week",
                    "month",
                    "agenda"
                ],
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                dataSource: {
                    batch: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: ROOT + "Diary/fetchDiary",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        update: {
                            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/update",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/create",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        destroy: {
                            url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/destroy",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return kendo.stringify(options.models);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "taskId",
                            fields: {
                                taskId: {from: "TaskID", type: "number"},
                                title: {from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: {required: true}},
                                start: {type: "date", from: "Start"},
                                end: {type: "date", from: "End"},
                                startTimezone: {from: "StartTimezone"},
                                endTimezone: {from: "EndTimezone"},
                                description: {from: "Description"},
                                recurrenceId: {from: "RecurrenceID"},
                                recurrenceRule: {from: "RecurrenceRule"},
                                recurrenceException: {from: "RecurrenceException"},
                                ownerId: {from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1},
                                isAllDay: {type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay"}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    filter: {
                        logic: "or",
                        filters: [
                            {field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 1},
                            {field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 2}
                        ]
                    }
                },
            })
        })
    }
}
```

And the when it initialises the data string that comes over is:

```
          [{"TaskID":4,
            "OwnerID":2,
            "Title":"Bowling tournament",
            "Description":"",
            "StartTimezone":null,
            "Start":"Date(1370811600000)",
            "End":"Date(1370822400000)",
            "EndTimezone":null,
            "RecurrenceRule":null,
            "RecurrenceID":null,
            "RecurrenceException":null,
            "IsAllDay":false}]
```

But it isn't working and I am getting an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTimezoneOffset' of null
```

My PHP:

```
public function fetchDiary() {
    echo '[{
        "TaskID":4,
        "OwnerID":2,
        "Title":"Bowling tournament",
        "Description":"",
        "StartTimezone":null,
        "Start":"Date(1370811600000)",
        "End":"Date(1370822400000)",
        "EndTimezone":null,
        "RecurrenceRule":null,
        "RecurrenceID":null,
        "RecurrenceException":null,
        "IsAllDay":false}]';
}
```

Comment: add slash before Date function =>  "Start":"/Date(1370811600000)",
        "End":"/Date(1370822400000)",